# excel csv not displaying string column correctly

Tags: excel, string, csv

I have a csv file below:

```
RTC ID,RTC Type,RTC URL,ADS URL,RTC Unreachable Children,# RTC Unreachable Children
199420,story,https:/xxx890,httxxxxxxxxx9420,"199701,199858,199608",3
```

If I preview it in vscode, it looks fine, but when opened in excel, the "RTC Unreachable Children" column is displaying incorrectly.

[image]

I've tried clicking to highlight the entire column and changing the text formatting in excel but string / general / dont work, is there any way I can tell excel to display the commas separating each number inside the quotation marks?

[image]

Comment: As you're experiencing, Excel is rather terrible (IMO) with CSVs. You probably have to import the CSV file (not open, import), and then specify that column as Text.

Comment: I can import csv (in data tab), but where would I specify col as text? after its imported? Would I do that by selecting the letter above my column to highlight everything in that col and specify as text somehow? Thanks

Comment: @POVR2 during the import you can select how to import each column.  This must be done DURING the import.  Once the import finishes the data in Excel will be corrupted and cannot be reversed.

Comment: This worked, i had to go through these steps: 1) open new excel 2) go to 'data' tab, import from csv 3) choose csv 4) choose 'transform data' before importing 5) go to the column and select it 6) go to data type and set as 'text' 7) import csv, done

Comment: @POVR2 also make sure you save it as an xlsx and not a csv, otherwise you will need to go through those steps every time.

Answer (score 0):

This worked, i had to go through these steps:

1. open new excel
2. go to 'data' tab, import from csv
3. choose csv
4. choose 'transform data' before importing
5. go to the column and select it
6. go to data type and set as 'text'
7. import csv
8. save as .xlsx or something else (dont save as .csv)
   done

Thank you @POVR2 and @ScottCraner in the comments